# What does '[WDS] Disconnected!' error mean with webpack and Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm currently working on a Django project that uses Vue.js for the frontend. I keep getting the "[WDS] Disconnected!" error every time the page gets refreshed. That is, the website is fully functional and has no issues, but the error pops up for every time I reload the page.

```
[WDS] Disconnected!
close                webpack:///(webpack)-dev-server/client?:172
initSocket           webpack:///(webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js?:26
dispatchEvent        webpack:///./node_modules/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js?:219
_close               webpack:///./node_modules/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js?:1097
```

I'm running the website on localhost:8000 and the frontend on port 8080 as a local grid instance with a certificate file set up.

Is this normal behavior? I tried updating npm like some suggested, but that didn't do anything.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It means you turned off your Webpack Development Server

Comment: How does that work @Phil? I thought I am making a persistent connection. That is, while I navigate the website, no more errors are shown. It's only when I reload the site.

Answer (score 15):

[WDS] is the `Webpack Development Server`. You see it on refresh, because the socket gets broken, which triggers the "error". Yes, it is normal behavior, and only shows when you are using the `Webpack Development Server`.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the server again! that worked for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).